# try to create tree list from database by php .. whats wrong

Tags: php, list, tree

i just get

```
﻿﻿secondsecondsecond
```

this my code

```
    function getListaa($id){
            $sql = "select * from programs where itemRoot = '".$id."'";
            $strss = "";
            $this->dao1 = new DataAccess("localhost", "root", "", "ecommercedb");
            $this->dao1->fetch($sql);
            while(($rows = $this->dao1->getNextRow()) != null)
            {
                if (($this->dao1->executeNum("select * from programs where itemRoot = '".$rows['itemId']."'")) > 0) 
                {
                    if($id != 0) $strss .= "".$rows['itemName'];
                    $strss .= "";
                    $strss .= $this->getListaa($rows['itemId']);
                    $strss .= "";
                    if($id != 0) $strss .= "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $strss = "".$rows['itemName']."";
                }
            }
            return $strss;
        }
```

this is my table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `programs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `programs` (
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemName` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `itemPrice` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemDesc` text,
  `itemRoot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `programs`
--

INSERT INTO `programs` (`itemId`, `itemName`, `itemPrice`, `itemDesc`, `itemRoot`, `itemDateTime`) VALUES
(1, 'root', NULL, NULL, 0, '2013-12-15 13:22:03'),
(3, 'second', NULL, NULL, 1, '2013-12-15 13:22:13'),
(4, 'frist', NULL, NULL, 1, '2013-12-15 13:22:36'),
(5, 'secondfrist', NULL, NULL, 3, '2013-12-15 13:23:46'),
(6, 'secondsecond', NULL, NULL, 3, '2013-12-15 13:23:46'),
(7, 'fristfrist', NULL, NULL, 4, '2013-12-15 13:24:02');
```

this is my data

```
+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+
| itemId             | ItemName     | itemPrice     | itemDesc   | itemRoot |
+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 1                  | root         | NULL          | NULL       | 0        |
| 3                  | second       | NULL          | NULL       | 1        |
| 4                  | frist        | NULL          | NULL       | 1        |
| 5                  | secondfrist  | NULL          | NULL       | 3        |
| 6                  | secondsecond | NULL          | NULL       | 3        |
| 7                  | fristfrist   | NULL          | NULL       | 4        |
+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

and this is DataAccess Layer Code

```
    conn = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass);
            mysql_select_db($dbname, $this->conn);
        }

        /**
        * Execute a query like insert, delete or update
        * @param $sql string
        * @return void
        */
        function execute($sql) {

            return mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        }
        function executeNum($sql) {

            return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql,$this->conn));
        }
        /**
        * Fetches a query resources and stores it in a local member
        * @param $sql string
        * @return void
        */
        function fetch($sql) {
            $this->result = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        }
        /*function getRowsNum(){
            return $this->result->num_rows;
        }*/
        /**
        * Returns an associative array of a query row
        * @return Array
        */
        function getNextRow() {
            if( $row = mysql_fetch_array($this->result) )
                return $row;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

now , problem is fixed !!!!!!!
and this is my solution:

```
    function getListaa($id){
            $sql = "select * from programs where itemRoot = '".$id."'";
            $strss = "";
            $dao1 = new DataAccess("localhost", "root", "", "ecommercedb");
            $dao1->fetch($sql);
            while(($rows = $dao1->getNextRow()) )
            {
                if (($dao1->executeNum("select * from programs where itemRoot = '".$rows['itemId']."'")) > 0) 
                {
                    if($id != 0) $strss .= "".$rows['itemName'];
                    $strss .= "";
                    $strss .= $this->getListaa($rows['itemId']);
                    $strss .= "";
                    if($id != 0) $strss .= "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $strss .= "".$rows['itemName']."";
                }
            }
            unset($dao1);
            return $strss;
        }
```